# NestJS RabbitMQ @golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq how to mock a service call to publish

Tags: testing, jestjs, rabbitmq, nestjs

I have a working pub/sub implementation with the @golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq module.

I want to write a service spec to test the publish method of MessagingService which makes a call to the AmqpConnection publish method. How can I mock the publish method in the test?

**MessagingModule**

```
import { RabbitModule } from '../rabbit/rabbit.module';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { MessagingService } from './messaging.service';

@Module({
  imports: [
    RabbitModule,
    MessagingModule,
  ],
  providers: [ConfigService, MessagingService],
  controllers: [],
  exports: [MessagingService],
})
export class MessagingModule {}
```

**MessagingService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { AmqpConnection } from '@golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq';
import { QueueMessage } from 'src/models/queue-message.model';
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class MessagingService {
  private readonly exchange: string = this.configService.get<string>('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE') || 'drs-encrypt.exchange';
  private readonly routingKey: string = this.configService.get<string>('RABBITMQ_ROUTING_KEY') || 'drs-encrypt';
  private readonly logger = new Logger(MessagingService.name);

  constructor(
    private readonly configService: ConfigService,
    private readonly amqpConnection: AmqpConnection
  ) {}

  // Publish the queue message to the exchange
  public async publish<T>(queueMessage: QueueMessage): Promise<void> {
    this.logger.log(`publishing queueMessage to exchange: ${this.exchange} routing key: ${this.routingKey}`);
    await this.amqpConnection.publish(this.exchange, this.routingKey, queueMessage);
  }

}
```

MessagingService - Spec

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { MessagingService } from '../messaging/messaging.service';
import { AmqpConnection } from '@golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq'
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

describe('MessagingService', () => {
  let service: MessagingService;

  type MockType<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: jest.Mock<{}>;
  };

  const mockFactoryAmqpConnection: () => MockType<AmqpConnection> = jest.fn(() => ({
    publish: jest.fn(() => AmqpConnection),
  }));

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        ConfigService,
        MessagingService,
        {
          provide: AmqpConnection,
          useFactory: mockFactoryAmqpConnection,
        },
      ],
      controllers: [],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<MessagingService>(MessagingService);

  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });  

});
```

Answer (score 1):

What you did seems correct in the module setup, but since you didn't provide the test case it is difficult to know what went wrong.

However, you can try to provide a simple object as a mock, instead of a factory, and use it to check whether it was called with the correct inputs:

```js
   const amqpConnectionMock = { 
     publish: jest.fn()
   };
   const bindingMock = {
     exchange: 'test_exchange',
     routingKey: 'test_routing_key',
   }

   beforeEach(async () => {
    jest.clearAllMocks(); // start fresh
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        MessagingService,
        // you might want to mock the config too to provide a custom config for the test suite
        {
          provide: ConfigService,
          useValue: {
            get: () => bindingMock,
          },
        },
        {
          provide: AmqpConnection,
          useValue: amqpConnectionMock,
        },
      ],
      controllers: [],
    }).compile();

    await module.init(); // trigger nestjs lifecycle events

    service = module.get<MessagingService>(MessagingService);

  });
```

The test case could be like:

```js
  it('should publish', async () => {
    const message: QueueMessage = { ... } // <- your message here
    
    await service.publish(message);
   
    expect(amqpConnectionMock.publish).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      bindingMock.exchange,
      bindingMock.routingKey,
      message,
    );
  });
```

P.S: Not related to the question directly, but you could consider injecting the logger in the service too. That would allow replacing it in the test module to avoid polluting your test logs with unnecessary messages.